# skip first line of a csv using camel EIP spliter process all other lines and aggregate all lines including the skipped line

Tags: split, apache-camel, splitter

is there a simple way to skip the first line of a csv, header, using camel EIP spliter process all other lines and aggregate all lines including the skipped line? 
I need to convert the date of each record in a CSV file, but skip the first line which is the header. I'm trying to use the camel EIP splitter. 
thank you!

```
<route 
    id="core.predix.consumer.route"
    autoStartup="true" >
    <from id="predixConsumer" ref="predixConsumer" />   
    <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />
    <split streaming="true" > <!-- strategyRef="enrichmentAggregationStrategy" stopOnException="true"> -->
        <tokenize token="\n"/> 
        <log message="Split line ${body}"/>
            <!--  <process ref="EnrichementProcessor"/> -->
    </split>
    <to uri="{{fileDestinationEndpoint}}" />
</route>
```

Comment: failed to mention, It really doesn't matter if it is a csv or not, .txt is acceptable, just need to skip the header, the first line, of a file, process til end and then aggregate the entire file including the header. am hoping there is something that doesn't involve much Java code to handle it.

Comment: <choice>
        <when>
         <simple>"${property.CamelSplitIndex} > 0"</simple>
         <process ref="dateconverterprocessor" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little late but...

put the logic  in an aggregator ...

```
 <route
    id="fadec.core.PostFlightReportProducerRoute"
    autoStartup="true">
    <from uri="seda:postFlightReportProducer" />
     <split streaming="true" strategyRef="statusAggregationStrategy">
     <simple>${body}</simple>
        <log message="inbound Post Flight Summary Report message body: ${body}" />
        <process ref="postFlightReportMarshaler" />
        <to uri="velocity:templates/postFlightReportSummary.vm" />
        <log message="Velocity output: ${body}" loggingLevel="INFO" /> 
     </split>
 <wireTap uri="{{DFEndpointTest}}fileName=/${header.aircraftMetadata.outputPath}/${header.ship}_${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}.csv" /> 
     <choice>
        <when>
            <simple>${body} == null</simple>
            <log message="body is NULL, do not send NULL body!" />
            <stop></stop>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <process ref="xlsxProcessor"/>
            <wireTap uri="{{DFEndpointTest}}fileName=/${header.aircraftMetadata.outputPath}/${header.ship}_${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}.xlsx" />
            <log message="Sending data packet: ${header.aircraftMetadata.outputPath}/${header.ship}_${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}.xlsx" />
            <stop></stop>             
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
 </route>

public class StatusAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StatusAggregationStrategy.class.getName());

    @Override
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Arrived    | oldExchange  |  newExchange | Description
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // A         | NULL         |  A            | first message arrives for the first group
        // B         | A            |  B            | second message arrives for the first group
        // F         | NULL         |  F            | first message arrives for the second group
        // C         | AB           |  C            | third message arrives for the first group
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        log.info("Status Aggregation Strategy :: start");

            if ( oldExchange == null ) {  //This will set the 1st record with the Header
            log.info("old Exchange is Null");
            String body = newExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
            newExchange.getIn().setBody(body);
            return newExchange;
        }

    //Each newBody msg exchange will have 2 records, a header and a data record
    String newBody = newExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
    String existingBody = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
    StringBuilder osb = new StringBuilder();

    log.info("New Body exchange: " + newBody);
    log.info("Old Body exchange: " + existingBody);

    String SkipRecord = "";
    String addRecord = "";
    Scanner osc = new Scanner(newBody).useDelimiter("\r\n|\n");
    while ( osc.hasNextLine() ) {
     SkipRecord = osc.nextLine();
     //osc.nextLine();  //move past header
     log.info("aggregation: skip record: " + SkipRecord);
     if (  osc.hasNextLine() ) { 
       addRecord = osc.nextLine();
       log.info("aggregation addRecord: " + addRecord );
       osb.append(addRecord).append(System.lineSeparator());
     } else { log.error("bad newBody message exchange, has no data record!"); }
    }
    osc.close();

    log.info("Joined exchange: Old body: " + existingBody + " New body: " + osb.toString());
    oldExchange.getIn().setBody(existingBody + osb.toString() );

    log.debug("Status Aggregation Strategy :: finish");

    return oldExchange;

    } //Exchange process
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work. I would think that this would work because it should only execute what's inside the  statement if the property.CamelSlitIndex > 0, but it gets executed for each line, even when CamelSplitIndex =- 0.

is this a bug, or am I using it incorrectly???

```
<route 
    id="core.pre.consumer.route"
    autoStartup="true" >
    <from id="preConsumer" ref="preConsumer" /> 
    <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />
    <split streaming="true" > <!-- strategyRef="enrichmentAggregationStrategy" stopOnException="true"> -->
        <tokenize token="\n"/> 
        <log message="Split line ${body}"/>
        <choice>
          <when>
            <simple>"${property.CamelSplitIndex} > 0"</simple>
            <process ref="timeStampEnrichmentProcessor" />
            <log message="Camel Split Index is greater than zero: ${property.CamelSplitIndex}" />
          </when>
        </choice>           
    </split>
    <log message="body: ${body}" />
    <to uri="{{fileDestinationEndpoint}}" />
</route>
```

Comment: Try to print the headers after your tokenize to see what headers are available and their values.

Comment: thank you Rashti, would you have an example of how to do this in blueprint xml, I've found an example in java dsl. ? .to("log:like-to-see-all?level=INFO&showAll=true&multiline=true"))

Comment: I see that the camel split index is incrementing however the statements inside the <when></when> is being executed when the index is 0 ? CamelSplitIndex: 0, CamelSplitIndex: 1, .... CamelSplitIndex: 10

Comment: also, I've found a function with the simple language that supposedly does this, however, I do not know how to execute it. does anyone have an example? Camel 2.19: The skip function iterates the message body and skips the first number of items. This can be used with the Splitter EIP to split a message body and skip the first N number of items.

Comment: does anyone have an idea as to why the statements inside the when on index > 0 are being executed when the index is zero 0 ? am i doing something wrong? is this a bug? just trying to understand. thanks

Comment: did you try exchangeProperty.CamelSplitIndex instead of property.CamelSplitIndex?

Comment: Rashti, no, unfortunately that doesn't work either.same thing. the process inside the when gets executed

Comment: Assuming you are not able to switch to the java dsl? It has much better documentation and easier to work with.

Comment: yeah, unfortunately i'm stuck without much rework. I am going to try using the exchange property inside the process class to skip processing if not > 0 - otherwise I will skip camel altogether and write something. it is ashame there is nothing on any of this. I don't know if I should file a bug report or not. seems this should work

Comment: Unfortunately I am not that versed with the xml syntax as I primary use the java dsl and there it works for sure as I have used complex choices and worked fine. You could try to ask the Camel gitter channel to see if one of the Camel devs will answer. But the documentation is getting a complete revamp so stay tuned for that.  By the way, one really bad part of doing everything in xml is that it makes debugging a pain.

Answer (score 0):

You may use option
[org.apache.camel.dataformat.csv.CsvDataFormat#setSkipHeaderRecord(true)](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-core/3.0.0-RC1/org/apache/camel/model/dataformat/CsvDataFormat.html#setSkipHeaderRecord-java.lang.Boolean-)

Here how it may work:

```java
package app;

import io.github.dgroup.j2gp.processor.GroupByParent;
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.dataformat.csv.CsvDataFormat;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;

import java.util.List;


public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CamelContext ctx = new DefaultCamelContext();
        ctx.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {

                CsvDataFormat csv = new CsvDataFormat();
                csv.setFormat(CSVFormat.EXCEL);
                csv.setSkipHeaderRecord(true); // <- ignore first line (e.g. csv header)

                from("file:data/inbox?noop=true")
                    .unmarshal(csv)
                    .split(body())
                    .log("Reached ${body}")
                    .process(exchange -> {
                        List<String> line = exchange.getIn().getBody(List.class);
                        ...
                    });
                    ...
            }
        });

        // start the route and let it do its work
        ctx.start();
        Thread.sleep(10000);

        // stop the CamelContext
        ctx.stop();
    }
}
```